# Show main content first then show menu while loading mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I came up with this idea but i don't know where to start.
I'm sure it's not something new.

I have a website where 1 menu is very heavy in loading because it has a very complicated and large query.
What i want to accomplish is that the mainpage shows first while the menu is loading with some kind of progress bar.

The website is in PHP. the menu is called by:

```
require('menu.php');
```

Comment: You need asynchronous requests. Google AJAX or XHR. Don't expect to learn this in a snap.

Comment: is this possible (or advisible) with iframe?

Comment: iframes are one way to make asynchronous calls. I can't tell you which one is better technically, but I'd rather go with `xhr` because iframes add javascript layers and are a little bit harder to manipulate, as well as they can cause further trouble with same origin policy and stuff you wouldn't expect.

Answer (score 0):

Please use JS and Ajax. at first, remove the slow "require('menu.php');" from the HTML and show your page. Then once that has shown load "require('menu.php');" with ajax and after it has completed write it to your page.
check this answer too:

[Adding loading image while PHP script runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312531/adding-loading-image-while-php-script-runs)

u can add php code to different file Show the loading image And then call this function

from the link above :

```
function Load()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    var url;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {           
            //(optional)do something with response: xmlhttp.responseText
            document.getElementById("area").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById("loadingimage").src = "afterloading.gif";
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","phpfile.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

this function goes to your javascript place then either call it with jquery after document finishes loading or

```
<body onload="Load()">
```

and in body place something like

```
<img id="loadingimage" src="loading.gif"/>
<div id="area">...</div>
```